# Akka Persistence: How to override circuit breaker configuration?

Tags: akka-persistence

We are working on an application using akka-persistence and akka-persistence-jdbc. Every thing works great but lately we had an issue where the database went down for a very short time and we saw persistence failing even when the database was up and we could see the following exception:

```
akka.pattern.CircuitBreakerOpenException: Circuit Breaker is open; calls are failing fast
```

Can someome help us with how can we define the circuit breaker configurations ourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since akka-persistence-jdbc doesn't configure its own circuit breakers, it inherits the default Akka Persistence circuit breakers.

The journal's circuit breaker is thus configured at `akka.persistence.journal-plugin-fallback.circuit-breaker` and the snapshot store's circuit breaker at `akka.persistence.snapshot-store-plugin-fallback.circuit-breaker`.  You'll most likely want to reduce the `reset-timeout` in both, which is the time from when the breaker trips until it will move to half-open (basically it allows one request through (rejecting everything else) and decides whether to close or open the circuit breaker based on the result).  For the journal plugin, the default `reset-timeout` is 30 seconds and the default for the snapshot store plugin is 60 seconds.

Comment: Thank you Levi, I was reading the same from the refernce configuration at: https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/main/akka-persistence/src/main/resources/reference.conf